# A guide to differences between v8 versions 3.28.73 and 3.14.5.9

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm trying to compile a node.js extension module against node-v0.12.2 and some v8 3.28.73 classes had lost methods which were there in version 3.14.5.9 (used in node-v0.10.10). Of course, this is only one of the errors I'm facing. 
The error message follows

```
‘AsciiValue’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’.
```

The function which calls the method is very short

```
char * getStringArg(v8::Local<v8::Value> value) 
{
    v8::String::AsciiValue string(value);
    char *str = (char *) malloc(string.length() + 1);
    strcpy(str, *string);
    return str;
}
```

Where can I find a guide to the big differences between these v8 versions?

I'm advancing by way of trial and error.

Comment: I don't think there is a v8 API comparison between node 0.10 and 0.12, but using [`nan`](https://github.com/rvagg/nan) will help you bridge the gap more easily. However it doesn't cover *everything*, so instances like this one you've noted in particular will require you to change `AsciiValue` to `Utf8Value`. This is safe because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.

Comment: I'm circling around nan from yesterday, because it implies a near full rewrite of the cc sources. But I will give it a try, Thank you.